# Custom cavity for speaker system?

Tags: acoustics

Typical acoustic speakers come mounted in boxes. The shape of the boxes is important because the speaker throws pressure both forwards and backwards, so the back pressure goes into the box and resonates, thus the shape and material of the box has a noticeable effect on the sound quality. A constraint on speaker manufacturers is the size of this box.

In a home, however, if a speaker is mounted in a wall or other special enclosure, it may be possible to build a large or unconventional sound box for the speaker. Has there been any research done on the design and characteristics of such custom enclosures?

Comment: "The shape of the boxes is important" - do you have any evidence for that? The *volume* of a *sealed* box is important, but you don't need a box at all if you use a wall (or the ceiling) as an infinite baffle.

Comment: @alephzero You could start by reading this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudspeaker_enclosure

Comment: As a rule of thumb, whether you mount the drivers in a wall or just in a stand alone box, you want to avoid having walls that are parallel to each other to avoid generating resonances. That is why you see so many high-end speaker systems that have "funny" shapes . :-)

Comment: This is a good read to get you started : http://www.nutshellhifi.com/library/speaker-design1.html : highlights problems past and present etc